# jQuery and $_GET

Tags: php, jquery, get

Let's say I have this url: www.example.com/test.php?page=4

How do i retrieve the value of $_GET['page'] with jQuery? o_O

Comment: Haven't seen the -get tag before.

Comment: I don't understand this question. $_GET is a server-side concept.

Comment: He is trying to access URL parameters from jQuery

Comment: sshow, indeed. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery Query String Object Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have jQuery or you don't want to use a plugin, you can use this code from [netlobo.com](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html):

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

then use it as follows:

```
var pageNumber = gup( 'page' );
```